# Find and Delete all Comboboxes in Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I want to use VBA to delete all comboboxes in a sheet (form control type not active X)

I have

```
For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
s.Delete
Next s
```

The problem is it deletes all my shapes, and I'm having trouble finding the logic just to delete comboboxes (which have different names)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
With ActiveSheet.DropDowns
Do While .Count > 0
    .Item(1).Delete
Loop
End With
```

or just

```
activesheet.dropdowns.delete
```

Comment: Never heard of an object `dropdowns`, does it still exist on a sheet in 2020? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3832788/1705829) is another usecase which does not work.

Comment: @Timo - yes, still works in 2020...  If you're having a problem with some code maybe worth posting a question about it?

Comment: Tim, it does not delete the ActiveX Elements, just the "normal" ones, which is what the questioner wanted. I however want to `clear` all dropdowns in a loop, not delete. BTW I use Edge and when I put a `@` at the beginning to address you, the `@Tim` gets deleted. Ok, seen [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 0):

If the only Forms you have are these comboboxes, then:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If s.Type = 8 Then
            s.Delete
        End If
    Next s
End Sub
```

Comment: I get index out of range.

Comment: the `s.type` is `msoformcontrol` which is 8 as of [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype)