# Excel for macOS - access ComboBox from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, combobox

I am facing issue with accessing value of ComboBox.
I have assigned macro to it, but I cannot find out, what name it has assigned. Because of "object properties" is missing in macOS Excel VBA, I have no idea how to resolve this. My Excel is in Slovak Language (therefore suggested method for macro was Rozbaliť1_Zmena), but when I am accessing it through "Rozbaliť1" , code has problem with diacritics in the name of object.

[image]

```
Sub ComboBox_Change()

    Dim strSelectedItem As Variant
    strSelectedItem = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).???.Value
    MsgBox strSelectedItem

End Sub
```

Comment: It is not working even with english version: strSelectedItem = Sheets("REPORT").DropDown1.Value

Comment: Resoltion is strSelectedItem = Sheets("REPORT").DropDowns("Drop Down 1").Value

Answer (score 0):

Name can be changed in the left corner of the table (where "Range" is displayed). Regarding code, I have found resolution to this issue:

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()
    Dim strSelectedItem As Variant
    Dim dd As DropDown

    Set dd = ActiveSheet.DropDowns("Drop Down 1")
    Set MyRange = Sheets("HELP").Range(dd.ListFillRange)
    
    strSelectedItem = MyRange(dd.Value)
    
    MsgBox strSelectedItem
    
End Sub
```

More info: [Get dropdown value in VBA and get the name of the dropdown...nowhere to be found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826353/get-dropdown-value-in-vba-and-get-the-name-of-the-dropdown-nowhere-to-be-found/3832788)